# How to prevent xkbmap reset?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb, capslock

I use two keyboard layout, and I use CapsLock to switch to the first layout, and Shift+CapsLock to switch to the second. To do that I use the following command:

```
setxkbmap -option grp:shift_caps_switch,lv3:ralt_switch us,ua
```

The only problem that these settings are reseted eventually by some daemon. So I have to use cron script to monitor the settings every minute. The question is how to make xkbmap setting permanent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the `/etc/default/keyboard` file:

```
XKBLAYOUT="us,ua"
XKBOPTIONS="grp:shift_caps_switch,lv3:ralt_switch"
```

This should be effective after next reboot.